# Python3: Does a call to pymysql.rollback() require a commit?

Tags: python-3.6, commit, rollback, pymysql

I'm using python3.6 and pymysql 0.7.11.

The call to *rollback* rolls a transaction back, according to the documentation.

A call to *commit* finalises a transaction.

My question is whether after a call to *rollback* it is prudent to call *commit* ... ?

Answer (score 1):

this is not really a python question but about mysql transactions.

you can read about it at  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx  for example.

in short: you need to start a transaction to rollback or commit it.

usually autocommit is enabled if you don't want to use transactions manually .. in that case mysql creates a transaction for every statement.

Comment: Plus1 for the link. But ... can you be a bit  more explicit with regard to my question?

Comment: both, rollback and commit are commands to end a transaction ... commit to save the state and rollback to remove all commands that were done since the start.

Comment: Nice, thanks, can you update your answer with that information, then I can accept it.